# Dashed vertical colored line with chosen width in tabularx

Tags: tabularx

In the code below, I was able to produce dashed grey vertical lines of a certain width. I want to replace the solid line by a dashed one. I tried to add `:` using the `arydshln` package, but it leads to error.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\geometry{left=2mm,right=2mm}
\geometry{top=3mm,bottom=3mm}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\color{gray}\vrule width 0.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{>{\hsize=\hsize}X?>{\hsize=\hsize}X}
\hline\\[0.2pt]
A & B\\
D & E\\
\end{tabularx}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: simple with the `nicematrix` package since it combines with `tikz`  -- have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{tabularx}{0.4\textwidth}{X:X}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\hline\\[0.2pt]
A & B\\
D & E\\
\end{tabularx}
\label{table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to adapt the line width?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {  
    dashed 1/.style = 
      {
        red ,
        dash pattern = on 2pt off 3pt ,
        line width = 1 pt 
      } ,
    dashed 2/.style = 
      {
        blue ,
        dash pattern = on 1pt off 1pt ,
        line width = 2pt 
      }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{2cm}wc{2cm}}
\hline
A & B\\
D & E\\
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed 1] (row-1-|col-2) -- (row-3-|col-2) ;
\draw [dashed 2] (row-1-|col-3) -- (row-3-|col-3) ;
\draw [dashed 1] (row-2-|col-1) -- (row-2-|col-3) ;
\draw [dashed 2] (row-3-|col-1) -- (row-3-|col-3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```